# How to get a List from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a characterList class that has a `final List <Character> character` field;
How can I access the `character` from the `SWMain` class?

SWMain class:

```
class _SWMainState extends State<SWMain> {
  Icon customIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
  static Text titleText = Text("Star Wars API");
  Widget customSearchBar = titleText;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar()
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Character>>(
          future: fetchCharacters(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? CharacterList(character: snapshot.data)
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

characterList class:

```
class CharacterList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Character> character;
  CharacterList({Key key, this.character}) : super(key: key);
...
}
```

Comment: Same way you access any other class instance variable--its's not clear to me what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

`CharacterList({Key key, this.character}) : super(key: key);`

this is the constructor.

You are using a stateless widget so you can directly access via variable name which is `character` in your case.

if you are using a stateful widget so you have to access it via `widget.character`
Thanks.